# twig {{ base_url }} not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I'm using codeigniter 2x and I integrate twig properly. I create a simple web site and test it. my problem is when I call a page through a function my images are not loading properly.please help me.

this is my controller

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['result']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
    /*print_r($data);*/
    $this->twig->display('home.html',$data);
    //$this->load->view('content_view.html',$data);
}
```

this is my view

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <img src="{{ base_url }}images/footer.png" alt="Image" style="width: 100%;" />
</div>
```

Comment: when I use <img src="../}images/footer.png" alt="Image" style="width: 100%;" /> it's working.but then again home page images are not loading.

Comment: check you correclty  AUTO-REGISTER FUNCTIONS & FILTERS  as described [here](http://edmundask.github.io/codeigniter-twiggy/)

Comment: that document is about twiggy. I'm using twig bro.

Comment: Sorry for the mistacke

Comment: have you tried `{{ base_url() }}` ?

Comment: How did you integrate? Did you register `base_url` with `addFunction()` of Twig?

Comment: I tried {{ base_url() }}. but it's also not working

Comment: I just copy and past twig folder and php file to library folder and put twig.php controller file into config folder.can you please tell me more about addFunction().

Comment: i found my error.I use firebug to check my image path.Then I found my image path was wrong."http://localhost/pelikanartline.com/search/images/left_content.png" .it includes my search controller too.please help me to remove this controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found error the controller

```
$data['result'] = $this->mymodel->search($keyword); 
$this->twig->display('home.html',$data);
```

should change to this

```
$this->data['result'] = $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
$this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this additional variable into your controller:

```
$data['base_url'] = base_url("/");
```

Send all the data into Twig for rendering:

```
$this->twig->display('home.html',$data);
```

Use `{{ base_url }}` in your home.html twig template - to get your base_url.